# How fix or disable proxy in phonegap?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build, phonegap-desktop-app

When my app do `POST` request its work. look like

> http://192.168.0.165:3000/proxy/http%3A%2F%2Fhomestead.app%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fuser%2F

But when I do next request with `GET` that don't work.
I think it because phonegap lost what I send in my `params`. How I can fix it or disable proxy in phonegap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this in your `index.html` file

```
(function() {
    var xhr = {};
    xhr.open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url) {
        console.log(url);
        if(url.indexOf('/proxy/') == 0){
            url = window.decodeURIComponent(url.substr(7));
        }
        xhr.open.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(window);
```

If you begin to face the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" problem use this extension for chrome ([modheader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en)) and add a response like this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://yourip:3000
```

If you are making multiple requests and wish the session be shared between them then add another response like this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```